# C# SqlCeException - a parameter is missing

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, sqlexception

I have a windows mobile 6 application I am developing. It is accessing a SQL Server CE database and I am receiving the following error:

> A Parameter is missing. [Parameter ordinal = 1]

I haven't used SQL Server CE too much but an almost identical application using SQL Server 2008 executed this code with no problems. I can't figure out why it is telling me the parameter is missing!

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;


namespace ElectricBarcodeApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection(
            ("Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), "ElectricReading.sdf") + ";Max Database Size=2047")));
            try
            {
                // Connect to the local database
                conn.Open();
                System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

                SqlCeParameter param = new SqlCeParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@Barcode";
                param.Value = textBarcode.Text.Trim();

                // Insert a row
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Location, Reading FROM Main2 WHERE Barcode LIKE @Barcode";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                DataTable data = new DataTable();

                using (SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        data.Load(reader);
                    }
                }

                if (data != null)
                {
                    this.dataGrid1.DataSource = data;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ElectricReadingDataSetUtil.DesignerUtil.IsRunTime())
            {
                // TODO: Delete this line of code to remove the default AutoFill for 'electricReadingDataSet.Main2'.
                this.main2TableAdapter.Fill(this.electricReadingDataSet.Main2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I read some articles saying this error can occur when a decimal is passed because of some msft error but I am not using any data containing decimals. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add the parameter to the command, should be something like

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: Also: don't call .ExecuteNonQuery() with that SELECT query, make sure to add the parameter to the command _after_ setting the commandtext, and don't call Read() before loading the datatable.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Okay so adding the parameter to the command fixed my error. I added it right after cmd.commandtext = "select..." per your suggestion. As to your other suggestions why should I not call ExecuteNonQuery like that and what would be the correct way? Also you said not to call Read() before I load the datable, so your saying I shouldn't have if(reader.Read()) before data.load(reader)? Why? Not questioning you, just trying to learn. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @Jason - calling .ExecuteNonQuery() will actually go to the database and run your query. The code will wait while it runs. And then the server will throw the results away, and when you reach .ExecuteReader(), it will go to the server and run the query _again_. .ExecuteNonQuery() does _nothing_ here except slow you down.  Also, you should remove the reader.Read() call because this actually advances the datareader past the first record. When you then go to load it into a dataset, that first record was already read, and so will be be loaded.

Comment: Okay thank you! I was actually having trouble with reading the first data row and was wondering why!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (without knowing what your `SQL` text actually is) that you forgot to insert your parameter.

Try modifying it to something like this:

```
       conn.Open();
            System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Barcode", txtBarcode.Text.Trim());
            //SqlCeParameter param = new SqlCeParameter();
            //param.ParameterName = "@Barcode";
            //param.Value = textBarcode.Text.Trim();


            // Insert a row
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Location, Reading FROM Main2 WHERE Barcode LIKE @Barcode";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SqlCeParameter param = new SqlCeParameter();                 
   param.ParameterName = "@Barcode";
   param.Value = textBarcode.Text.Trim();
   param.Add(@Barcode);
```